# writing Mongo DB output connector for manifoldcf

Tags: mongodb, connector, manifoldcf

We are trying to push repository contents to MongoDb through apache manifold CF.

And we don't find any sample code for custom output connector. 
Is it possible? can someone please help on this?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

If you read the documentation carefully you will find that the default database used for ManifoldCF is HSQL and the developer has tried the setup with various other databases. For our project we went forward with the postgreSQL database as that was the best recommended one. You could also go with mySQL database. Default connectors are not provided for connection to the mongodb. 
You could search for a book called "ManifoldCF in Action" by Karl Wright if you want to custom build your connectors.

But I do not find any reason why you  would like to go with mogodb as the data is very less and postgreSQL/mySQL could do the job very well.

If you have any more questions regarding ManifoldCF, feel free to contact me directly though my email.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance, we reused Elasticsearch output connector code and connected MongoDB using manifold CF.

Comment: Please do accept the answer if you feel it was near to the correct one.